# Как вернуть MonoDevelop в unity?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, monodevelop, unity3d-editor

Внезапно пропала моно и вместо нее стал открываться Visual studio. Пытался скачать с офф сайта, установить xamarin studio, но все VS открывается. В preferences только browse и открыть стандартной программой для данного расширения есть. Два раза переустановил юнити (при удалении говорит что все связанные файлы удалит, но при повторной установке и запуске сразу кидает на окно выбора проекта с уже залогиненой учётной записью, будто ничего и не было)
Помогите пожалуйста, VS, Xamarin итд не подходят мне из-за времени запуска и после запуска компьютер просто ложится на лопатки и виснет даже в браузере, а также нет подсказок, поэтому пришлось заморозить проект до решен я проблемы

Comment: Версия Unity какая?

Comment: можете попробовать visual studio code

Comment: @Suvitruf , 2018 года

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если версия Unity 2018, то [ничего удивительного](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/):

> Начиная с Unity 2018.1 на Windows будет поставляться Visual Studio
>   2017 Community, MonoDevelop-Unity больше не будет поддерживаться.

Comment: Печально. Но если VS нативно поддерживается то почему в подсказках нет ничего от юнити? Получается теперь кодить в слепую?

Comment: @Vefery о каких подсказках речь:

Comment: @Suvitruf я думаю он имеет ввиду автодополнение ключевых слов и вставку сниппетов из Unity, которые включаются плагинами на VS.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**: Edit -> Perferences... External Tools

**Mac**: Unity -> Preferences... External Tools

Comment: Нет такого пункта

Comment: напишите версию VS

Answer (score 0):

Заходим в верхней панели на вкладку Edit >> Preferences... >>> External Tools >> External Script Editor и меняем Visual Studio на MonoDevelop (easy boy!)